# page web method not working in ajax call where web service method is calling perfectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery, webmethod

i want to implement jquery slider for range of price and i try to call a page web method using jquery `ajax` but its not working in case of web page method  but in case i just change the URL attribute of ajax call to a `webservice` then its called perfectly . I am trying this from several hours and not finding any logic behind this . here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var startPosition;
        $(document).ready(function () {          
            var hdnMinPrice = 142;
            var hdnMaxPrice = 969;
            $("#slider").slider(
              {
                  min: hdnMinPrice,
                  max: hdnMaxPrice,
                  range: true,
                  values: [hdnMinPrice, hdnMaxPrice],
                  step: 50,
                  slide: function (event, ui) {
                      $('#lbl').text(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);

                  },
                  start: function (event, ui) {
                      startPosition = ui.value;
                      //alert('Slider started at: ' + ui.value);
                  },
                  stop: function (event, ui) {                     
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          //url: SearchResult.aspx/FilterByPrice",                                                    
                          url: "WebService.asmx/InsetSubscriber",
                          data: "{email: '250@yahoo.com'}",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (msg) {
                              alert('Thanks');
                              // Do something interesting here.
                          }
                      });                     
                      return false;
                  }
    });
        });
    </script>
```

commented out URL option is page web method and following is definition of web page method

```
 [WebMethod]

    public void FilterByPrice(string email)
    {
        Response.Write("min" + email);
        //Response.Write("max" + max);
    }
```

where web service method is as following which is working :

```
[WebMethod]
    public void InsetSubscriber(string email)
    {
        DALSubscriber objSubscriber = new DALSubscriber();
        objSubscriber.InsertSubscriber(email);

    }
```

once again i repeat my question here after this code segment . **Page web method is not working where same method using web service method is running in jquery ajax call**

Comment: So it does not work in Ajax when call it using url: SearchResult.aspx/FilterByPrice is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because PageMethods **must be static on your page**

Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void FilterByPrice(string email)
{
    // Use HttpContext.Current.Response instead
    // Response.Write("min" + email);
    //Response.Write("max" + max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check you web.config in the httpmodule section. It must have the ScriptModule for ScriptManager because Web page method works with it

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add EnablePageMethods="True" and  EnableScriptGlobalization="True"

hope it will work

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.